# Is it possible to RECEIVE SMS texts using Azure Communication Services Python SDK?

Tags: python, sdk, azure-communication-services

The Azure Communication Service Github repo says that the service has the capability to "Send and Receive SMS messages",

[image]

But I only see "Send" functions in both Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/sms) and the Python SDK Github repo (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/communication/azure-communication-sms).

I don't see anything about RECEIVING SMS on the ACS roadmap either.

How is this done using the ACS Python SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACS already supports receiving messages through `Event Grid`. In summary you need to register to the `SMS Received` event, and you should receive Event Grid events each time linked number receive a message.

For more information you can check [SMS FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/sms/sms-faq#how-can-i-receive-messages-using-azure-communication-services) and our QuickStart sample here [Quickstart: Handle SMS and delivery report events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/handle-sms-events)

When you set up the `Event Grid` you can configure it to forward the notification to a `Web Hook` for example and in this way, you can notify your application about the incoming message.